# Stored procedure IFELSE block not entering the ELSE block

Tags: sql-server, database, if-statement, stored-procedures, ssms

I have a table called Employee_Info with Employee_ID,Name,Age and Address columns.I want my query to return the EmployeeID if a particular name exists, if doesnt exist then it has to return another select condition where it returns all rows with null Address values. But my query is not jumping to the else block but instead showing a table with empty columns of the IF block itself. And i have to be using the concept of Stored Procedures for this This is my code:

```
ALTER PROC spEmployee
@Emp_Name VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
  IF @Emp_Name =@Emp_Name
     SELECT Emp_ID FROM EMPLOYEE_INFO WHERE Emp_Name=@Emp_Name
  ELSE 
     SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_INFO WHERE Address IS NULL
 END
```

Comment: `IF @Emp_Name =@Emp_Name` -> this comparison doesn't make sense. If you pass `'Bob'` you're saying `IF 'Bob' = 'Bob'` which will always be true. Did you mean `IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.EMPLOYEE_INFO WHERE Emp_Name = @Emp_Name)`?

Comment: As noted, you have a fundamental logic flaw in your IF expression. You compare the parameter to itself - which will always evaluate to TRUE as long as the value of the parameter is not null. Fix it as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

`EXISTS` operator can be used to check whether the particular record is existing in the table. Here we can use `IF` condition with `EXISTS` operator and get the result we expect.

Please find the below answer.

```
ALTER PROC spEmployee
@Emp_Name VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EMPLOYEE_INFO WHERE Emp_Name=@Emp_Name)
    SELECT Emp_ID FROM EMPLOYEE_INFO WHERE Emp_Name=@Emp_Name;
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_INFO WHERE Address IS NULL;

END;
```

Comment: There is NEVER a good reason to count if you only need to know if a row exists. Nor do you need to store that value in a variable - which you have used incorrectly in this attempt. Bad habits are hard to unlearn.

Comment: @SMor How to know whether that employee exists?

Comment: Updated answer, thanks!

Comment: @divya sharma Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Yes Thankyou soo much @shehanpathirathna for the help. I'm new to this and the logic you gave has helped me!!